# Angular Datatables - fnInfoCallback equivalent

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, datatables, angular-datatables

**Scenario in jQuery**

Formerly in `jQuery` I would achieve the following depicted in the image below:

[image]

Each **Tab** contains a datatable and the value shown against the tab name is the count of the number of records filtered for the datatable which is displayed by the datatable as shown below:

[image]

In `jQuery` I would achieve this by adding the following callback (`fnInfoCallback`) in my datatable initialization

```
$('#mydatatable').dataTable({
    sDom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order": [[0, "asc"]],
    "columns": [
        { className: "align-middle"},
        { className: "align-middle"},
        { className: "align-middle"},
        { className: "align-middle"},
        { className: "align-middle"},
        { className: "align-middle"}
    ],
    "ajax": {
        "url": "api/dt",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.status = "new";
        }
    },
    "fnInfoCallback": function (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) {
        $scope.newCount = iTotal;
        return sPre;
    }
});
```

so as to access the following field (`recordsFiltered`) which is the datatable response from the server:

```
// Datatable Response from server
{
      "draw": "2",
      "recordsTotal": "824",
      "recordsFiltered": "82",
      "data": [

  ]
}
```

**Problem Statement**

I am using the following library for **Angular Datatables** https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables in my Angular 8 app.

So now I would wish to achieve the same using **Angular Datatables**. I have searched their examples but haven't found anything to do with such a callback. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Angular Datatables` has a `Settings` interface as below:

```
interface Settings {  
    /**
     * Feature control the processing indicator. Since: 1.10
     */
    processing?: boolean;        

    /**
     * Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode. Since: 1.10
     */
    serverSide?: boolean;

    /**
     * Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source. Since: 1.10
     */
    ajax?: string | AjaxSettings | FunctionAjax;

    /**
     * Data to use as the display data for the table. Since: 1.10
     */
    data?: any[];

    /**
     * Data to use as the display data for the table. Since: 1.10
     */
    columns?: ColumnSettings[];

    /**
     * Assign a column definition to one or more columns.. Since: 1.10
     */
    columnDefs?: ColumnDefsSettings[];
    
    /**
     * Initial order (sort) to apply to the table. Since: 1.10
     */
    order?: Array<(number | string)> | Array<Array<(number | string)>>;        

    /**
     * Footer display callback function. Since: 1.10
     */
    footerCallback?: FunctionFooterCallback; 

    /**
     * Table summary information display callback. Since: 1.10
     */
    infoCallback?: FunctionInfoCallback;
   
    /**
     * Row draw callback.. Since: 1.10
     */
    rowCallback?: FunctionRowCallback;
    
}
```

I have truncated some of the settings because the list is huge and just left the familiar ones. Seems they did a pretty good job here.

Of interest is the `infoCallback` and I used it as follows (just as you'd use it in `jQuery`)

```
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  order: this.order,
  columnDefs: [
    {className: 'text-right', targets: this.columnAlignment}
  ],
  infoCallback: (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) => {
    this.recordCount = iTotal;
    return sPre;
  }
};
```

This **this.recordCount = iTotal;** stores the number of records filtered to the `this.recordCount` field.

The in my html, this is how I used the `recordCount` field where `dtTableNew`, `dtTableInProgress` and `dtTableCompleted` are all instances of my implementation of a custom datatable object.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href="#new-upload">New <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{dtTableNew.recordCount}}</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#in-progress">In progress <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">{{dtTableInProgress.recordCount}}</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#completed">Completed <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">{{dtTableCompleted.recordCount}}</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is what triggered my solution [The old AngularJS API Documentation](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/api)

Comment: How did you used recordCount? Can you please share the complete solution?

Comment: @SunnyBatabyal, I've added the html part